# Is it recommended not to take hardware wallets through international airport security scanners?

Tags: security, hardware-wallet

I suspect this won't get an answer as it is highly speculative (on the scanning technology in airports) but does anyone have any information or informed views on whether you can take hardware wallets/signers through international airport security scanners and not leak any (private) key material? Or is it recommended one does not take hardware wallets/signers through international airports unless they are part of a multisig and the other signing devices aren't on you at the same time?

Comment: Yeah this question does seem potentially speculative. It is the whole point of a SE though to avoid leaking a secret by all means, so it sounds unrealistic just observing through a scanner could breach its protections. That said, it seems to me the bigger risk at TSA is "unlock this thing or we [confiscate / lock you up / enter threat]". So yeah, speculative question. :) Maybe try a more objective one at a hardware stackexchange?

Comment: @AntoinePoinsot: Thanks, I'll close.